# Unable to IMPORTXML Free Cash Flow from Yahoo Finance using Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I've been successful using IMPORTXML to pull into Google Sheets for Enterprise Value and Growth Estimates Next 5 years (per annum) but I'm unable to pull in Free Cash Flow. I have blocked JavaScript to rule out if that is the issue. If someone could help me it would be great? Below are the IMPORTXML methods I have been successful and unsuccessful with.

Enterprise Value:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL","//*[@id='Col1-0-KeyStatistics-Proxy']/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
```

Growth Estimates Next 5 years (per annum):

```
=IMPORTXML("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL","//*[@id='Col1-0-AnalystLeafPage-Proxy']/section/table[6]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")
```

Free Cash Flow:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/cash-flow?p=AAPL","//*[@id='Col1-1-Financials Proxy']/section/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[12]/div[1]/div[2]/span")`
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the value you expect at "Free Cash Flow"?

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say that the [link](https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/cash-flow?p=AAPL) is javascript generated. And `IMPORT` functions don't work on that.

#### Testing the link:

[image: Output]

#### Alternative:

- You can try to find an alternative non-javascript generated site that would provide the same data. See similar [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512078/14606045). Although I can't find exact same data from any other sites, this [site](https://www.stock-analysis-on.net/NASDAQ/Company/Apple-Inc/Valuation/EV-to-FCFF) seems similar especially on the operating cash flow (aside from TTM values). You might want to check that.

#### Reference:

- [Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510738/importxml-imported-content-is-empty/)

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me how you tested it was in fact using JavaScript? As when I blocked JavaScript through Chrome is still presented the value I was after which made me lead to believe it was non-JavaScript generated value.

Comment: As you can see above @D-CRUZR, you only need to make the xpath `"//*"`. If it returns a javascript code, then it is javascript generated

Comment: Thanks, though I think the JavaScript is only in relation to the table and charts that is down the right side of the page. As that is not shown when I block JavaScript. Could I be correct with that evaluation? Regardless I think I need to learn how to use API's as I'm not a huge fan how the IMPORTXML loads.